# Syncing my knockoutjs models with my backend (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, knockout.js

Has anyone implemented something similar?

The problem I have is the fact that we're not using REST. The current plan is the following:

Create a controller called `sync($modelName, $action)` and throw all requests at that. 
Create an interface called "syncable" and force models to implement it.

How it works:

```
GET http://localhost/sync?modelName=User&action=update&first_name=Peeter
```

This will look for a model named `UserModel` that implements the syncable interface. If found, update its parameters and `update();` to db.

The syncable interface is to enable per-record actions. E.g. "Only record owner can update this record" or "Only admin can delete this record".

Comment: Not sure what the question is here, are you asking how to serialize/deserialize in PHP?  How to create that querystring from a model? What exactly are you not able to accomplish?

Comment: I'm looking for design ideas on how to implement this. The posted design is what I came up with.

Comment: I guess the PHP part is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a fully function REST API framework into symfony 1.4. It supports JSON and JSONP. I've open sourced it, so you're welcome to use it. We're using it in production with a lot of traffic, so it's pretty stable and we've had great feedback from the consumers. It's really flexible and very fast to write API methods. We also have a documentation page that allows you to make test queries. It's one of the best API docs I've seen.

https://github.com/homer6/blank_altumo

See this (below) for an example of an API controller. This contoller only shows GET, but PUT, POST and DELETE are fully implemented.

https://github.com/homer6/blank_altumo/blob/master/htdocs/project/apps/api/modules/system_event/actions/actions.class.php

If you need help getting it going, I'm willing to spend a few minutes to explain its design or get it working for you.

Hope that helps...

Comment: I don't suppose there is an equally production ready Doctrine variant? Haha

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But you could always fork it and I could work with you to adjust where needed. Don`t know if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an app I'm working on, so I implemented a ChangeTracker that subscribes to my observable properties, and tracks any changes made.  Then, at any later point, I can call something like:

```
viewModel.changeTracker.commit();
```

which is responsible for massaging my change objects into a format that the server understands, and ships it off for processing.

Here is a little fiddle demonstrating the idea.  http://jsfiddle.net/ggoforth/pCX8c/2/

Note: I've had a string of days where I've been working till 3am so there may be a better way of doing this, and I'm just to exhausted to realize it :)

Comment: Ah, bummer, not sure what happened.  I'll see if I can get it back or recreate it.

Comment: Here's another fiddle, thought this is pretty quickly thrown together.  In each of my viewmodels I implement a change tracker that subscribes to all of the view model properties.  it then tracks changes any time they are updated and provides a "sync" function that can be called to send the data to the server.  This example just shows the tracking part:  http://jsfiddle.net/ggoforth/efXDq/